# Get value in a column on pd.groupby for iteration

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Currently I have a `df` as following:

```
ID    Origin    Destination     Age    Gender
1       A           B           17       M          
1       B           A           17       M
3       C           D           20       F       
3       D           E           20       F
3       E           C           20       F
```

I want to make an XML file from this `df`, so I used a code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('trips.csv')
trips = df.groupby('ID')
with open("output.txt", "w+") as f:
   f.write("<population>\n")
   for a, b in trips:
      f.write(f'   <person id="{a}">\n')
      f.write(f'   <attribute age="{a.Age}" gender="{a.Gender}" >\n')
      f.write("    </attribute>\n")
   
      for x in b.itertuples():
         f.write(f'    <trip origin="{x.Origin}" destination="{x.Destination}">\n')
         f.write("     </trip>\n")
      f.write("     </person>\n")
   f.write("</population>\n")
```

However, it shows error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Age'
```

The output that I'm aiming for is like:

```
<population>
  <person id="1">
  <attribute age="17" gender="M">
  </attribute>
     <trip origin="A" destination="B">
     </trip>
     <trip origin="B" destination="A">
  </person>

  <person id="3">
  <attribute age="20" gender="F">
  </attribute>
     <trip origin="C" destination="D">
     </trip>
     <trip origin="D" destination="E">
     </trip>
     <trip origin="E" destination="C">
     </trip>
   </person>
</population>
```

I guess it is because of the `pd.groupby()`? What should I do to access the values in a cell in the grouped `df` so that I can use that in the iteration? Or is there something wrong with my loops (i.e. in the `for a, b in trips`?)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id is correctly in variable `a` but the Age and Gender would actually be in variable `b`.
Try this:

```
with open("output.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("<population>\n")
    for a, b in trips:
        f.write(f'    <person id="{a}">\n')
        f.write(f'    <attribute age="{b.Age.iat[0]}" gender="{b.Gender.iat[0]}">\n')
        f.write(f'    </attribute>\n')
        
        for o,d in zip(b["Origin"], b["Destination"]):
            f.write(f'        <trip origin="{o}" destination="{d}">\n')
            f.write("        </trip>\n")
        f.write("    </person>\n")
    f.write("</population>\n")
```

Comment: Ah yes that works! I've tried to use b.Gender, but on the output file there are other numbers also showing up so I thought that won't work. Thanks!

Comment: That's because `b.Gender` is a `pandas.Series`. Since you have the same age for each id, you use `b.Gender.iat[0]`